# asp:login CreateUserUrl wont work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make login page using asp:login control, i want to give option to unregisterd users to get them selfs registerd. .

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" CreateUserUrl="~/Signup.aspx" CreateUserText="SignUP" >
    </asp:Login>
```

But it is not redirecting to the signup page instead page keeps refreshing when clicked on signup link. .

Plz help me to resolve this issue. .

Thanx. .

Comment: You will need to provide more information for example what does the codebehind do and or check for in regards to checking user `authentication / authorization`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Signup.aspx` page or its containing path will need to be accessible to anonymous users. If you have your application locked down to ensure users log in before accessing parts other than the credentials page, then this page will also redirect them to log in!

As an example, you will need to do something like the following in your web.config:

```
<location path="Signup.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```